# How to make ZeroBrane Studio use another Lua version?

Tags: lua, ide, version, zerobrane

Zero Brane studios runs with Lua 5.1, I want to upgrade to 5.2.
I installed [Lua for Windows](https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/)

Then I downloaded the file "[lua-5.2_Win64_bin.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.2/Executables/)" unzipped it and moved the content to the folder of "Lua for Windows".

Then I started ZeroBrane studios, and under **Edit -> Preferences -> Settings: User**, I wrote this code to the file **user.lua**

```
path.lua = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.2\Lua52.exe'
```

Then I saved the file, and restarted ZB Studio. To check if this was successfull, I compiled this code:

```
print(_VERSION)  --Output = Lua 5.1
```

So it did not worked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Using `'C:\Program Files...'` as the path doesn't quite do what you need; you better be using `[[C:\Program Files...]]` as it doesn't interpret backslash sequences.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't quite"? So what does it do?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. You actually just have to go to "**Project -> LUA Interpreter**" and select your desired version.